# TYPO3 v10 routeEnhancer generates slug but can't resolve it

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I have a weird behavior in my own extension when using a slug.

The slug generator in my TCA looks like this:

```
        'slug' => [
        'label' => 'Slug',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'slug',
            'generatorOptions' => [
                'fields' => ['title'],
                'fieldSeparator' => '/',
                'prefixParentPageSlug' => true,
                'replacements' => [
                    '/' => '',
                ],
            ],
            'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
            'eval' => 'uniqueInSite',
            'default' => ''
        ],
    ],
```

It generates the slugs correctly.
It is also persisted as expected in the database.

The routeEnhancer looks like this:

```
ReferenceDetail:
 type: Extbase
 limitToPages:
  - 82
 extension: reference
 plugin: referencedetail
 routes:
  - routePath: '/{ref}'
    _controller: 'Reference::show'
    _arguments:
      ref: reference
 aspects:
  ref:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_reference_domain_model_reference
    routeFieldName: slug
```

In my frontend everything looks fine. Links look like:
https://xyz.info/reference/detail/name-reference/

But when clicking on it I end up with a 404.
When I switch from `routeFieldName: slug` to `routeFieldName: name` or `routeFieldName: uid` it works perfectly? Has anyone an idea what might goes wrong with my slug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

This issue is related to: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91397

The objects I store are outside of my pageRoot becasue I have a multidomainsite.
Therefore you have to set  `'eval' => 'unique'` instead of  `'eval' => 'uniqueInSite'` in your TCA Slug config.